# How to set ng-class if?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have array in Angular JS with string values: `["dog", "cat"]`

How to set class using directive `ng-class` where `item.type in array`?

I mean this case:

```
ng-class="item.name in filter.categories? 'red' : ''"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function that check if your value is in the array:

```
$scope.isAnimal = function(val) {
    for(let i = 0; i < $scope.animals.length; i++) 
        if(val == $scope.animals[i]) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Then, you can apply your ng-class from the result of this function:

```
ng-class="{'red': isAnimal(item.name)}"
```

With a ternary operator, it could be:

```
ng-class="isAnimal(item.name) ? 'red' : ''"
```

Comment: @hAGARA Fixed! :-)